# How to get month name from prompt by using Date object and then calculate next birthday

Tags: javascript, date

In my javascript program I am trying to calculate birth years. I have created prompt dialogue boxes which accept different values and I am displaying these values but month values given by user is not showing correct in second line. user has entered 8 and it's showing October. Can anyone help me to identify an issue ? How should I get values all three values from prompt to calculate birth year ?

code:

```js
var today = new Date();

var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

var birth = new Date();

var myMonth = prompt("What month were you born in?");
var myDay = prompt("What day were you born on?");
var myYear = prompt("What year were you born in?");

var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var dateLoc = document.getElementById("dateField").innerHTML = "Today is " + today;

var birthField = document.getElementById("birthField")
  .innerHTML = "I was born on " + monthNames[birth.getMonth()] + ' ' + myDay + ',' + myYear + '.' +
  '(' + myMonth + '/' + myDay + '/' + myYear + ')';


var secondsBetween = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000
endDate = new Date(today.getFullYear() + 1, myMonth, myDay);
var nextBirth = document.getElementById("nextBirth").innerHTML = "I am" + endDate + "Years old, and will turn"+  +"in" ;
```

```html
<p id="dateField"> </p>
<p id="birthField"> </p>
<p id="nextBirth"> </p>
```

output:

[image]

Comment: You display the month name with `monthNames[birth.getMonth()]`, but `birth.getMonth()` has no connection to the month the user entered.

Comment: It is the current month as `new Date();` create a date object with the actual  date. You need something like `birth = new Date(myYear, myMonth, myDay)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `birth.getMonth()` simply returns the **current** month, as `birth` is simply set to `new Date()`. As it's October at the moment, you'll always get `October` as a result.

Instead, you're looking to access the index provide by the user with `monthNames[myMonth - 1]`. The subtraction of `1` is needed because the index starts at zero, and months start at one. To have the correct month show up, simply enter the month number in the following example:

```js
var today = new Date();

var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

var birth = new Date();

var myMonth = prompt("What month were you born in?");
var myDay = prompt("What day were you born on?");
var myYear = prompt("What year were you born in?");

var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var dateLoc = document.getElementById("dateField").innerHTML = "Today is " + today;

var birthField = document.getElementById("birthField")
  .innerHTML = "I was born on " + monthNames[myMonth - 1] + ' ' + myDay + ',' + myYear + '.' +
  '(' + myMonth + '/' + myDay + '/' + myYear + ')';
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p id="dateField"> </p>
<p id="birthField"> </p>
<p id="nextBirth"> </p>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you....I am trying to calculate birth years as shown in code but it's not working. Could you please suggest me solution ?

Comment: That's an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378); something different to what you were initially asking for. To combine the two questions would make it **too broad**, and would mean the question would be considered '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)' for StackOverflow. Please break each point down into a specific action, and ask each one as new, individual question. You can link to this question with [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721303) in the new question if it helps to explain your point :)

Comment: @Age Can I totally ask new question related to this program ?

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem with `monthNames[birth.getMonth()]`, try `monthNames[myMonth - 1]` instead:

```
    var birthField = document.getElementById("birthField")
    .innerHTML = "I was born on " + monthNames[myMonth - 1] + ' ' + myDay + ',' + myYear + '.' 
    + '(' + myMonth + '/' + myDay + '/' + myYear + ')';
```

October is current month name, it's so due to `birth = new Date()`

Your next birthday could be obtained by (myMonth - 1) / myDay / (today's year + 1). Then to calculate seconds between two dates you may use

```
var secondsBetween = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000
```

It means that you have to covert input date to the javascript Date. In your case (just following [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/date-object-javascript)) it is pretty simple:

```
endDate = new Date(today.getFullYear() + 1, myMonth - 1, myDay);
```

Comment: I have one more doubt. How should I calculate birth years, days, hour, minutes and second until next birthday ? As we can't give date directly it depends upon user. So how should I do ?

Comment: it doesn't work...I updated my code see above...I also want to find how many years will turn next year...suppose current 25 next will be 26.